# wants to autoscroll flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to auto scroll my flatlist but when I run my code I cannot scroll auto and if I want to manual scroll it comes to index 0 after every 5 seconds ..
here is my all code of flat list and its refs function

in constructor

```
this.flatList1=null;
```

And in componentwillMount

```
componentWillMount(){

  setInterval(()=>{
    if(this.flatList1!==null){
      this.flatList1.scrollToOffset({ offset: 1 })
    }
  }, 5000);
}

<FlatList horizontal
  data={this.state.getallvideos}
  ref={flatList1 => { this.flatList1 = flatList1 }}
  renderItem={({item}) =>  

    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.playvideoinnetpage.bind(this,item.vd_link,item.vd_thumbnail,item.vd_id,item.vd_title)}>

      <Card
        containerStyle={{
          padding:0, 
          width:180,
          height:112,
          backgroundColor:'#000',
          borderColor:'#000',
          marginTop:10,
          marginLeft: 5,
          marginRight:5,
          marginBottom:5
        }}
        image={{uri:item.vd_thumbnail}}
        imageStyle={'stretch'}
      >

        <View style={{position:'relative',bottom:75,}}> 
          <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{color:'#fff',fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:14}}> {item.vd_title}</Text>
        </View>
      </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  }
/>
```

Comment: @manahor reddy  is that solution ??

Comment: No I just formatted question properly

Comment: thank you ..do you have any solution ??

Comment: No I don't know java script I am from android .

Comment: ok but anyways thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the answer here [ [How do I make a list (FlatList) automatically scroll through the elements using Animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475202/how-do-i-make-a-list-flatlist-automatically-scroll-through-the-elements-using) ]

```
scrollToIndex = (index, animated) => {
   this.listRef && this.listRef.scrollToIndex({ index, animated })
 }

 componentDidMount() {  // use componentDidMount instead since the WillMount is getting deprecated soon
   setInterval(function() {
     const { sliderIndex, maxSlider } = this.state
     let nextIndex = 0

     if (sliderIndex < maxSlider) {
       nextIndex = sliderIndex + 1
     }

     this.scrollToIndex(nextIndex, true)
     this.setState({sliderIndex: nextIndex})
   }.bind(this), 3000)
 }
```

You should essentially increment the index instead of setting it to 1 every 5000ms like in above code. Keep the currentIndex, maxIndex and use the scrollToIndex function after incrementing currentIndex like above. Do make sure you are modifying the state after updating the currentIndex using setInterval

Comment: where should I write scrollToIndex = (index, animated) => {
   this.listRef && this.listRef.scrollToIndex({ index, animated })
 }

Comment: in constructor ??

Comment: it is just a function. put it inside the class. not inside constructor. between constructor and componentDidMount

Comment: @DhananjaiPai , what if i want to maintain both automatic and manual scroll? This is not working properly. On manual scroll, index does increment but once the timer expires, it resets to the value which has been last scrolled?